# Add a vertical UITableView inside a UIScrollView

Tags: swift, uiview, uiscrollview, uikit

I have a screen that contains some content, and on the bottom of it I'd like to have a UITablView and I'd like that the two were synchronized. If I scroll the UITableView on the bottom, the content that's above the UIView would scroll as well, kinda like a sticky header but different in the sense that the entire screen could be filled by the UITableView.

How it is right now (the image on the bottom is simply me trying to add the element below):

[image]

How it should be - notice the list on the bottom, we can keep scrolling it.

[image]

This is my code right now:

```
//
//  HomeViewController.swift
//  FeatureExplorer
//
//  Created by Rodrigo Vieira on 10/04/22.
//

import UIKit
import Combine

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    var networkService = NetworkService.shared
    var observers = [AnyCancellable]()
    
    var rootScrollView: UIScrollView = {
        var sv = UIScrollView()
        sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        return sv
    }()
    
    var rootStackView: UIStackView = {
        var rc = UIStackView()
        rc.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        return rc
    }()
    
    var welcomeLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        
        label.text = "Welcome!"
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        
        return label
    }()
    
    var profileImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: HomePageImages.profileIconImage!)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        
        return imageView
    }()
    
    var searchBar: UITextField = {
        let textField = UITextField()
        
        var leftPaddingView = UIView(
            frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 0)
        )
        
        textField.leftView = leftPaddingView
        textField.leftViewMode = .always
        
        textField.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        textField.backgroundColor = .white
        textField.placeholder = "Search cocktails"
        
        textField.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        textField.layer.shadowOffset = .init(width: 1, height: 1)
        textField.layer.shadowRadius = 8
        textField.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
        
        return textField
    }()
    
    var screenContentContainerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 30
        
        view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
        view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
        view.layer.shadowRadius = 12
        
        return view
    }()
    
    var latestDrinksLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        
        label.text = "Last cocktails published"
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
        
        return label
    }()
    
    var recentDrinksCollectionView: RecentDrinksCollectionView = {
        let collectionViewLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        collectionViewLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        
        let collectionView = RecentDrinksCollectionView(
            collectionViewLayout: collectionViewLayout
        )
        
        return collectionView
    }()
    
    var popularCocktailsLabel: UILabel = {
        var label = UILabel()
        
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
        label.text = "Popular drinks"
        
        return label
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        
        addScrollViewLayout()
        addRootStackViewLayout()
        addWelcomeLabelLayout()
        addSearchBarLayout()
        addScreenContentViewLayout()
        addLatestLabelLayout()
        addRecentDrinksCollectionLayout()
        addPopularLabelLayout()
        addPopularDrinksTableViewLayout()
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        fetchAndDisplayPopularCocktails()

        view.backgroundColor = Colors.mainRedColor
    }
    
    func addScrollViewLayout() {
        view.addSubview(rootScrollView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            rootScrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            rootScrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            rootScrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            rootScrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    func addRootStackViewLayout() {
        rootScrollView.addSubview(rootStackView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            rootStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: rootScrollView.contentLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor
            ),
            rootStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: rootScrollView.contentLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor
            ),
            rootStackView.topAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: rootScrollView.contentLayoutGuide.topAnchor
            ),
            rootStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: rootScrollView.contentLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor
            ),
            rootStackView.widthAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: rootScrollView.frameLayoutGuide.widthAnchor
            )
        ])
    }
    
    func addWelcomeLabelLayout() {
        welcomeLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        profileImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
        rootStackView.addSubview(profileImageView)
        rootStackView.addSubview(welcomeLabel)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            welcomeLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: rootStackView.leadingAnchor,
                constant: 20
            ),
            welcomeLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: rootStackView.trailingAnchor,
                constant: -20
            ),
            welcomeLabel.topAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: rootStackView.topAnchor,
                constant: 20
            ),
            profileImageView.topAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: rootStackView.topAnchor, constant: 20
            ),
            profileImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: rootStackView.trailingAnchor,
                constant: -50
            ),
            profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60),
            welcomeLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: profileImageView.centerYAnchor
            ),
        ])
    }
    
    func addSearchBarLayout() {
        searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        rootStackView.addSubview(searchBar)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            searchBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: rootStackView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20
            ),
            searchBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: rootStackView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20
            ),
            searchBar.topAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: profileImageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20
            ),
            searchBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
        ])
    }
    
    func addScreenContentViewLayout() {
        screenContentContainerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        rootStackView.addSubview(screenContentContainerView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            screenContentContainerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: rootStackView.leadingAnchor
            ),
            screenContentContainerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: rootStackView.trailingAnchor
            ),
            screenContentContainerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: view.bottomAnchor
            ),
            screenContentContainerView.topAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: searchBar.bottomAnchor, constant: 25
            )
        ])
    }
    
    func addLatestLabelLayout() {
        latestDrinksLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        rootStackView.addSubview(latestDrinksLabel)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            latestDrinksLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20
            ),
            latestDrinksLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20
            ),
            latestDrinksLabel.topAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: screenContentContainerView.topAnchor, constant: 30
            )
        ])
    }
    
    func addRecentDrinksCollectionLayout() {
        addChild(recentDrinksCollectionView)
        
        recentDrinksCollectionView
            .view
            .translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        screenContentContainerView.addSubview(recentDrinksCollectionView.view)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            recentDrinksCollectionView.view.topAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: latestDrinksLabel.bottomAnchor,
                constant: 20
            ),
            recentDrinksCollectionView.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: view.leadingAnchor
            ),
            recentDrinksCollectionView.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: view.trailingAnchor
            ),
            recentDrinksCollectionView.view.heightAnchor.constraint(
                equalToConstant: 280
            )
        ])
    }
    
    func addPopularLabelLayout() {
        popularCocktailsLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        screenContentContainerView.addSubview(popularCocktailsLabel)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            popularCocktailsLabel.topAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: recentDrinksCollectionView.view.bottomAnchor,
                constant: 20
            ),
            popularCocktailsLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: rootStackView.leadingAnchor,
                constant: 20
            ),
            popularCocktailsLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: rootStackView.trailingAnchor,
                constant: -20
            ),
        ])
    }
    
    func addPopularDrinksTableViewLayout() {
        
    }
    
    func displayTwoFirstPopularDrinks(drinks: [DrinkModel]) {
        let firstPopularDrinkView = PopularDrinkView()
        rootStackView.addSubview(firstPopularDrinkView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            firstPopularDrinkView.topAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: popularCocktailsLabel.bottomAnchor,
                constant: 50
            ),
            firstPopularDrinkView.leadingAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: rootStackView.leadingAnchor,
                constant: 20
            ),
            firstPopularDrinkView.trailingAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: rootStackView.trailingAnchor,
                constant: -20
            ),
            firstPopularDrinkView.heightAnchor.constraint(
                equalToConstant: 300
            ),
            firstPopularDrinkView.bottomAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: rootStackView.bottomAnchor
            )
        ])
        
//        firstPopularDrinkView.addContentToView(drink: drinks.first!)
    }
    
    func fetchAndDisplayPopularCocktails() {
        networkService
            .fetchPopularCocktails()
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { completion in
                switch completion {
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                case .finished:
                    print("finished")
                }
            } receiveValue: { [weak self] value in
                self?.displayTwoFirstPopularDrinks(drinks: value)
            }
            .store(in: &observers)
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for helping out, really!

Comment: I recommend using tableView only, splitting UI into sections and cells. If you add tableView inside scrollView, it's harder to control reuse cell, content size, scrolling...

Comment: Could you give me an example of how I would achieve this? I would return a custom cell based on the index of the element, for example? Or it would be one section to the "static" content and other to the dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

As @son mentioned, I would suggest to go with a `tableView` or even better with a `collectionView` instead of a scroll view and split the UI into different cells.
But if adding a `scrollView` is what you want then try the following.

- Disable the scroll on the `tableView`.
- Add height to the tableView with `255` priority.
- Add `tableView.sizeToFit()`.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how I would use a CollectionView? I would return a custom cell based on the index of the element, for example? Or it would be one section to the "static" content and other to the dynamic? –